# What time Ethereum gas fee is calculated?

Tags: transactions, gas, flash-loans

When is Ethereum gas fee calculated during execution of contract.  I was wondering if i take out flash loan and if the trade happened to be profitable, will the profit be able to offset transaction fee or I would have to pay upfront?

Answer (score 4):

When you create a transaction you set two parameters:

- `gas`: Maximum amount of gas to be used
- `gasPrice`: Price to pay for each gas unit

To execute the transaction your account needs to have at least `gas * gasPrice` ether.

Before executing your account is charged with `gas * gasPrice`.

After the transaction has completed its execution unused gas and refunded gas are returned to your account.